# After Effects - Recreate a "distortion" or a special Radial Blur effect / Slowly pitch sound down

Tags: after-effects, audio, effects, special-effects

I would like to re-create an effect from the game Dishonored.
The FX happens when I teleport or when I slow down time, the screen gets some radial blur and a strange kind of distortion at the edges. While that happens, the game sounds also get pitched down slowly, depending on how much radial blur is on the screen. Here's a video showing the effect:

[Click me...](http://youtu.be/gLvY3I7WF5M)

Here's an another video, showing the game slowly slowing down, and the radialblur&distortion increases, sound slowly pitches down.

[Click me...](http://youtu.be/PuDjt7IZr2k?t=2m14s)

Answer (score 1):

You can recreate this effect with the `CC Radial Blur` effect set to "Fading Zoom" together with the `Ripple` effect or the `Turbulent Displacement` effect.
Apply these effects to an Adjustment layer above your video layer and add a round mask in the middle with some feather to have the blur and distortion only on the sides of the screen. Use separate Adjustment Layers for each effect to fine tune the strength of both effects with separate masks.

You also want to set the size wave size of the ripple effect to something like 60/30 to have it closer to the look in Dishonored and to not have it so uniform. Setting it to asymmetric might be a good ideas as well

To get even closer you can apply some other distortion effects available in After Effects, just play around a bit. The `Turbulent Displacement` effect is also a great alternative to the Ripple effect, might even be closer to the look in the game. It has a far less uniform displacement.

Comment: And what about the sound pitching down slowly and then back up?

Comment: I just tested it now, and the CC Radial Blur is the only thing that looks like Dishonored's Radial Blur effect. The ripple effect or the Turbulent Displace effect didn't do the same thing.

Comment: Well you should use them in conjunction not either the blur or the ripple/displace, the blur in Dishonered isn't just a static blur, it floating and distorting the picture, for that you need something to displace the picture.
To "slow down" sound you can't user After Effects, thats a whole other question for http://sound.stackexchange.com/.